# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when declaring button.frame

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting an error that says **Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)** when I'm trying to declare

```
    var buttonFrame = customButton.frame
```

Here is my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //sends menuOverlay to back on load
    parentView.sendSubviewToBack(menuOverlay)
    self.menuOverlay.hidden = true

    //sends sliderContainer back and makes its origin at the button
    let containerFrame = sliderContainer.frame

    let containerFrameX = containerFrame.minX
    let containerFrameY = containerFrame.minY

    var buttonFrame = customButtonOne.frame

    let sliderOriginX = buttonFrame.minX + (buttonFrame.width / 2)
    let containerTranslationX = CGFloat(containerFrameX-sliderOriginX)
    let containerTranslationY = CGFloat(-containerFrameY)

    self.sliderContainer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.001, 0.001)
    self.sliderContainer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(containerTranslationX, containerTranslationY)
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `customButtonOne`?

Answer (score 0):

If `customButtonOne` is an IBOutlet that isn't hooked up, it will be `nil`. `nil` doesn't have a `frame` property, hence the crash.

Make sure your IBOutlet is hooked up.